# What will be the difference between freshly installed OS and upgraded from previous version?

Tags: upgrade, system-installation

I had installed Ubuntu 13.10 when it was released. Now Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is ready to be launched. I wonder if there will be any different between a freshly installed Ubuntu and Upgraded from previous version.

I know there are some user files and Which will be preserved and a couple of software which i installed. But other than that what will not be upgraded.

PS: I already upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 RC.

Actually, I asked this because even after upgraded to "Release Candidate" and the default new wallpapers are still missing. Is there anything else?

Comment: When you upgrade the wallpaper does not change. In fact, none of your settings changes. The new wallpapers should be installed and should be there for you. Just right click and change the wallpaper to whichever you want. Similarly, if the new version does not come with something that was there by default in the old version, that app will still be there after the upgrade. If you do a new install it won't be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not do any major tweaking to some piece of software, ideally there should be no difference providing that the upgrade was successful.  Plus your data, contacts, etc are already there if you upgrade.  (However, you should always back it up just in case something goes wrong.)

Comment: The new wallpapers are now added. So, I doubt there might be something else.. something interesting.. not essentially important.